# Python - threaded pyinotify output. Better to write to file or to a string

Tags: python, theory, inotify

I have a pyinotify watcher running threaded, called as a separate class, at the moment it just prints its discoveries in a terminal window, if I wanted my script to make an action based on those changes am I better to:

A) modify an array with each notification

B) write to a file in /tmp and fetch it from my main script?

c) give up programming

thanks for any input,

Stewart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import Queue
changes = Queue.Queue()
```

and now use `changes.put` in the thread that discover the changes, `changes.get` in the thread that is supposed to act on those changes (there are several other useful methods in [Queue](http://docs.python.org/library/queue.html)
 that you should check -- also note, per the docs, that the module's renamed to `queue`, all lowercase, in Python 3).  Queues are intrinsically thread-safe and therefore often the best way to arrange cooperation among threads in Python.